# PHP SUM() function incorrect computation

Tags: php, eloquent

I'm using slim framework, what i want to do, is to compute a certain amount of a specific user ..

here's my table

```
load_up_id   user_id   amount
1            1         1000
2            1         1000
3            1         2000
4            2         3000
5            2         1000
```

i want to get the total amount of `user_id` no. 1, but instead of `4000` , it gives me `2000`

here's my code

```
$loadups = $this->loadupPayment->where('user_id', $this->auth->user()->user_id)->get();

$total_loadup = $this->loadupPayment->select(db::raw('sum(amount) as total_loadup'))->groupBy('user_id')->get();
```

Thank you in advance guys! :D

Comment: I don't see how _any_ query remotely resembling what you claim to be running could end up with an amount sum of 2000.  Are you sure this is the actual code and data you used?

Comment: Why group by keyword..?

Comment: Assuming the db engine grabs the last row of its type when in a group by statement. Still you would expect this to lead to 2000 + 1000 = 3000.

Comment: LOL query builders are so <barf> `SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_loadup WHERE user_id = :user_id`  Technically you don't have to group on user_id, when you have where user_id = #, because you want the sum of all the results....

Answer (score 1):

So you want a specific user's ID ? Try this one instead:

```
$total_loadup = $this->loadupPayment->select(db::raw('sum(amount) as total_loadup'))->where('user_id', $this->auth->user()->user_id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think rather than grouping by user id, you need to use the user id as a **CASE** in a sum statement. This is in essence a where cause in the SUM calculation, so you can say when the user id is the user id i want (in this case 1) add the value if not just ignore it.

Try something like this

```
$total_loadup = $this->loadupPayment->select(db::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN user_id = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as total_loadup'))->get();
```

You may want to parameterze the user id value in the above.

Hope this helps!